# What is the difference between L“the following:” and “the following:” when used with CStringW

Tags: c++, unicode

(I completely screwed up a similar question, I'm not sure if re-posting is the right way to do it, but because of my typo, the answers were utterly meaningless.)

Are there any differences between the two? Both compiles with vs2013.

CStringW str1 = "the following:"; CStringW str2 = L"the following:";

The strings are from afxstr: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx

I understand that the variant without L is casted via the appropriate cast operator but what problems can arise from using the form without L while I do NOT use any unicode characters between the quotation marks. Is this a good programming practice to use L"" even when you don't plan to use non-unicode chars or is there more to it?

edit: maybe I realized the answer. Is the main problem is that without L, I suffer the performance hit of calling an unnecessary operator method? But are both gives the same, correct result?

Comment: Yes, one of them requires a conversion. The other one doesn't.

Comment: Write sane code.  You are using C++, if you burn useless cycles on a string type that is incompatible with the string class and the operating system then you might as well use a scripting language.  Which usually get this right without help btw.